# Zend Framework Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a sql problem and i don't know how to fix it, I have tried a few things but..you know.So here is my query:

```
    /**
 * Returns a list with all the months for the archive
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function Archive()
{
 $q = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(`data`) AS `month`,YEAR(`data`) AS `year` FROM `posts` ORDER BY `data` DESC";
 $all = $this->fetchAll($q);
 if (count($all) > 0) {
  foreach ($all as $info) {
$months[] = array('month_name'=>$this->months($info['month']),'year'=>$info['year'],'month'=>$info['month']);
  }
  return $months;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

And my Error:

> > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)' in

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly through phpMyAdmin or the sql prompt? does it definatly return what you expect then?

Comment: unrelated to the question: you forgot to initialize $months as an array

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, finally I found that I was posting wrong value for a column. I was sending 2 values for a column. 
So, Check value of your parameters that are given to your function.

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing out a stage in the process? The query statement line as below:

```
    /**
 * Returns a list with all the months for the archive
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function Archive()
{
 $q = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(`data`) AS `month`,YEAR(`data`) AS `year` FROM `posts` ORDER BY `data` DESC";
 $stmt = $db->query($q);
 $all = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
 if (count($all) > 0) {
  foreach ($all as $info) {
$months[] = array('month_name'=>$this->months($info['month']),'year'=>$info['year'],'month'=>$info['month']);
  }
  return $months;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working just like you but finally I solved it by using Zend_Db_Select object instead a query string:

```
$select =  $this->getDbTable()->select(); // $this->select(); // 
$select->from('gallery', '*');
$select->where('id_category = ?', $id_category);
$select->where('active', 1);

$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);
```

Edited: Indented for code markup display.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems that this is a Zend Bug.

Source:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3311